# Excel - Rank a List of Dates Based on Comparison to Today's Date

Tags: excel, date, ranking

Is there a way in Excel 2010 to compare a column of dates against Today's date based on approximate match and then rank the dates based on proximity to today's date?  That was long so let me clarify.  I have a column of dates and I want to compare these against today's date even if there's no exact match to today's date.  I want to rank the list of dates based on comparison to today's date and would like to allow for ties.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide sample data, and expected results... that will help come up with a solution closer to what you want.

Comment: Are all dates in the past....or all in the future...or a mixture?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming dates in `A2:A20` then this formula in `B2` copied down will rank the dates in order of the closest to today (whether in the past or the future)

`=SUMPRODUCT((ABS(TODAY()-A$2:A$20)<ABS(TODAY()-A2))+0)+1`

If all dates are in the past (or all in the future) then a simple `RANK` function should suffice

Comment: Thanks for your response!!  Dates are in the past and the future, so SUMPRODUCT worked perfectly.  My remaining question is how this might be made to work in a table so that the correct formula is there as data gets added to new rows.  As soon as I drag this formula past the range of entered values I get a #VALUE error.  For instance, let's say there are only values in the range A2:A20 -- but I want the range to enable a potential range of A2:A1000.  As soon as I modify the formula to be A2:A21 I get a #VALUE error.  Is there any means of using OFFSET to adjust the range to the current range?

Comment: You can use a "dynamic named range" in place of A$2:A$20 - e.g. in Name Manager (on formula tab) define Data as `=OFFSET($A$2,0,0,COUNT($A:$A))` and use Data in the formula in place of A$2:A$20 (or you can use the OFFSET function directly in the formula) - I'm assuming that the dates will be continuous - i.e. no gaps

Comment: Thanks Barry Houdini!  Combined with OFFSET that worked perfectly. You are a magician!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [DateDif](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datedif.php) and compare the value of today's date (using TODAY) and then apply DateDif down a column and sort that column to order the dates.

If for some reason you don't have DateDif, using TODAY() and your cells with the dates you can just subtract them from eachother to get a difference for sorting.